# Reference request: Projective space $\mathbb{RP}^3$

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry

I have to write seminar paper in Projective geometry and the name of the seminar is (I would try to translate):

**Representation of the lines in  the projective space** $\mathbb{RP}^3-$Kernel, Lineal, Pliker's matrix, Pliker's coordinates - subsection.

I tried to search something about Pliker's matix, etc, but I failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try with "Plücker coordinates", and "Grassmannian".

Comment: @atricolf Ahh, Plücker is the key. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your paper :-)

Comment: @atricolf: Would you turn your comment into an answer, in order to get this out of the “unanswered” queue? Seems like it answered the question well enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Plücker coordinates", and "Grassmannian" are the right key words for what you are looking for. The object you want is the Grassmannian $G(2,4)$ (or $G(1,\mathbb P^3)$, depending on notations). You can realize this variety, the smallest Grassmannian which is not a projective space, as a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb P^5$, via the "Plücker embedding".

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive presentation of Plücker coordinates and the corresponding embedding on an advanced level is in Griffiths, Harris: *Principles of Algebraic Geometry.* A more elementary version is explained in chapter 8 of Cox, Little, O'Shea: *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms.*